# Should I always declare the 'ng' dependency in my angularjs modules?

Tags: angularjs

The following code causes an error:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [/*'ng'*/]);
    myModule.controller('testCtrl', function(){});

    var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule']); // this works
    console.log(injector); // it really works
    angular.injector(['myModule']); // this does not work, but I think it should
  </script>
</html>
```

The second call to `angular.injector` fails with:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $controllerProvider
```

I could fix this by explicitly declaring ng as a dependency of myModule as indicated with the commented code. Should I do this for all of my modules that contain controllers or did I find a bug in angularjs? And why can I build the module in the first place without declaring the ng dependency?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: why would you consider injecting a module you just declared, into itself? And where did idea of injecting `ng` come from?

Comment: It does not matter, what I want to do. I provided a minimal working example for a very irritating behavior of angular. And my question is, whether this is a bug in angular or whether I did not understand something.

Answer (score 0):

The angular.injector method expects two arguments:

- A root module which contains common dependencies
- A dependent module which contains specialized code

Specifically:

> AngularJS provides a module dependency system. You specify to Angular what is the root module that you would like it to load and it will also load up all the dependent modules. So for each app you can have a single module that depends upon other modules that contain common components. Again this is the documented way of doing things in AngularJS apps.
>
> When an Angular application starts with a given application module, Angular creates a new instance of injector, which in turn creates a registry of recipes as a union of all recipes defined in the core "ng" module, application module and its dependencies. The injector then consults the recipe registry when it needs to create an object for your application.

**References**

- [AngularJS Developer Guide | Providers - Note: A Word on Modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#note-a-word-on-modules)
- [Angular.js Issue #9692: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $compileProvider](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9692)
- [angular.module meaning of the second parameter "requires"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801179/113772)