# angular.module meaning of the second parameter "requires"

Tags: angularjs

Recall the method signature for [angular.module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module). If the second parameter, `requires` is provided, then we are creating a new module instead of retrieving an existing one. From all the documentation and examples I've seen, this parameter is always passed an empty array when used. My question is, is `requires` meant to be used for anything else besides telling Angular to create a new module instead of getting an existing one? What would happen if I instead passed it a non-empty array? Are those values used for any other purpose? Links with solutions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

requires meaning an array of modules which your module depends.

example:

**moduleA.js**

```
var customModule = angular.module ('ModuleA');
// controller, services, factories , etc codes here
```

**app.js (main app)**

```
var app = angular.module ("app", ["ModuleA"]);
```

if I just use:

```
angular.module ("app");
```

It means that i'm just retrieving the module named "app". Which is useable when controllers or directives or factories is defined in a different JS files and you want to configure it to the module "app"

Comment: This answer is correct. And in addition, angular has some modules that you can require. ngResource is one of them, and there are a few more.

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter is used to define the module's dependencies - i.e., a list of modules (module names, to be precise) that should be already loaded by the injector before the current module is loaded.

And here's how this param (stored in the module's `requires` property) is used: ([**injector.js/loadModules()**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/813117d/src/auto/injector.js#L751-L798)):

```
var runBlocks = [], moduleFn, invokeQueue, i, ii;
forEach(modulesToLoad, function(module) {
  if (loadedModules.get(module)) return; // skipping already loaded modules
  loadedModules.put(module, true);

  if (isString(module)) {
    moduleFn = angularModule(module); // prepared module object
    runBlocks = runBlocks.concat(loadModules(moduleFn.requires))
                         .concat(moduleFn._runBlocks);
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
return runBlocks;
```

As you see, this property can be used to set up a hierarchy of dependencies as well (when `ModuleFoo` depends on `ModuleBar` depending on `ModuleBaz`).