# angular.module: what does the second argument do?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-management

To reference an existing module in Angular 1.4, I do this:

```
angular.module('hotdog')
```

I can add things to the module like so:

```
angular.module('hotdog').factory(...).component(...)
```

To create the module in the first place, the module function needs that second argument of dependency modules.

```
angular.module('hotdog', ['sausage', 'bun'])
```

My question is, what does that list of dependencies actually do, if anything? I can take out the dependencies and it doesn't *seem* to break anything, even though I'm referencing services in the 'hotdog' module that belong to 'sausage' and 'bun'.

```
angular.module('hotdog', [])
```

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) isn't very helpful.

> "If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration."

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801179/angular-module-meaning-of-the-second-parameter-requires) but I'm not satisfied with the answers.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that once a module has been loaded it's available everywhere, even in modules that didn't explicitly require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument is for dependency injection. You may find [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) documentation a little more helpful.

> Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. Depending on a module implies that the required module needs to be loaded before the requiring module is loaded. In other words the configuration blocks of the required modules execute before the configuration blocks of the requiring module. The same is true for the run blocks. Each module can only be loaded once, even if multiple other modules require it.

If you declare dependencies or leave the second argument as an empty block [], it means that you are declaring a new instance of the module. If you leave it off completely, you are referencing an existing module.

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.